# How to delete all items from a DynamoDB table?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I want to delete all items (aka records/rows) in a DynamoDB table. I understand that the documentation advises to simply drop the whole table and re-create it, but I've created my table with AWS Amplify and I don't want to risk breaking the rest of my stack.

I've had a look at the DynamoDB API and the `aws-sdk` (I'm using javascript). I can delete single items in the database but I'm struggling to expand that to deleting multiple items.

```js
// Delete single item:
import { DeleteItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { ddbClient } from "./dynamoDbClient";

const tableName = "myTableName";
const itemId = "12f10644-546c-45f4-8309-c208061e9737";

export async function deleteItemDynamoDb() {
  const command = new DeleteItemCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
      id: {
        S: "12f10644-546c-45f4-8309-c208061e9737",
      },
    },
  });
  const response = await ddbClient.send(command);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I batch delete with DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465146/how-do-i-batch-delete-with-dynamodb)

Comment: Thanks! Those answers are from 2016 and I'm afraid I can't make sense of them. I think the sdk is a couple of versions on since then.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to use the `BatchGetItemCommand` to get all/many records from a table, so I have fudged a solution by combining AppSync and DynamoDB:

```js
export async function listCardsIncDeleted(): Promise<Card[]> {
  const getCardQueryString = `query listCards {
  listCards(limit:500) {
    items {
      id
      name
      _deleted
      _version
      status
    }
  }
}`;
  try {
    const response = (await appSyncClient.query({
      query: gql(getCardQueryString),
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    })) as {
      data: { listCards: { items: Card[]; __typename: "ModelCardConnection" } };
    };
    const { items } = response.data.listCards;
    console.log({ items });

    return items;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("ERROR");
  }
}

async function deleteAllTimes(arrayOfCardObjects: { id: string }[]) {
  let count = 0;
  for await (const curCard of arrayOfCardObjects) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 50));
    const deleteResponse = await deleteById(curCard.id);
    count++;
    console.log({ deleteResponse, curCardId: curCard.id, count });
  }
  return count;
}
async function listAppSyncThenDelete() {
  const listOfCards = await listCardsIncDeleted();
  const deletedAll = deleteAllTimes(listOfCards);
  return deletedAll;
}
```